# What makes ::AfxInitRichEdit2 fail and how do I fix it?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2012, cricheditctrl

I am building an existing MFC application with Visual Studio 2012. The application uses `"RichEdit20A"` controls and custom controls which inherit `CRichEditCtrl`.

During `InitInstance()` the application calls `::AfxInitRichEdit2()`, which calls `AtlLoadSystemLibraryUsingFullPath(L"RICHED20.DLL")`, which calls`LoadLibraryExW(pszLibrary, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32)`. The latter call fails and returns `NULL`. `GetLastError()` returns 87 (The parameter is incorrect.). This happens on both Win7 x64 and Win8 x64.

The failing call seems to have been introduced in the Visual Studio 2012 runtime (it is inside a conditional `#if NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN8`). The application worked just fine when built with Visual Studio 2008.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix (or work around) this issue? Alternatively, is there any way to "revert" the runtime to use the older load behavior?

Comment: Did you verify that RICHED20.DLL exists on the system?

Comment: Try to set `WINVER` to 0x600 or whatever it was before upgrading. If you created a new project in VS 2012 you likely ended up with a project targeting Windows 8. Change it i `targetver.h`!

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling Yes, RICHED20.DLL exists.

Comment: @l33t The project in its current form was created with VS2008, I believe (though not by me). We have no targetver.h, but it has a `#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choosing the proper target Windows version can be very important.  It is here, if you don't explicitly set it yourself then the Visual Studio assumes you'll target the latest and greatest.  Which is Windows 8 for VS2012.

Which includes a new option for LoadLibraryEx(), the LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32 option.  Available on Windows 8 but requires a [security patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533623) to be installed if you use it on Windows Vista, 7 or 2008.  It is a pretty critical one, clearly you don't have it installed.

If you want your program to be compatible with old or unpatched Windows versions then you need to change the target.  This is typically done by the `targetver.h` header file, assuming your MFC project was generated by a relatively recent wizard.  Modify it like this:

```
#pragma once

// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.

// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.

#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP    // NOTE: added
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

If you don't have targetver.h then put it anywhere before the #include for `<windows.h>`.  Tweak the value as desired.  Note that XP isn't currently supported by VS2012 but will be later.

Comment: A proper `#define _WIN32_WINNT` was in place, but the patch was missing. A follow-up: How could I have discovered that I require such a patch (besides asking the Stack Overflow community)?

Comment: I found it by reading the MFC code.  Not for everyone but this is why SO exists.

Comment: Could you reference where (and if applicable tell how) you found and/or deduced it for the sake of completeness?

Comment: Found what exactly?  The MSDN Library article for LoadLibraryEx contains the link to the KB article.